# Proving that $m^*(A\times B)=m^*(A)m^*(B)$ for lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

So we already know that $m^*(A \times B)\leq m^*(A)m^*(B)$ for an outer measure now I am trying to prove that it is an equality in Lebesgue measure. I know that is true if we consider one of the sets to be open, we need to use the Fubini theorem in the proof, now it is for an arbitrary set. I tried considering an open set $U$ that covers one of them and use the result I already know but I didn't get far. Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: do you agree that $m^*(A\times B) = \inf_{\text{open } U \supseteq A} m^*(U\times B)$? If so, then you're basically done

Comment: *Hint:* Use the [regularity of Lebesgue outer measure.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1077535/497335)

Comment: I can see that if that is true we are done , I just dont see why that is true. Shouldnt my open set be covering $A\times B$?

Comment: Looks trivial from definition of Lebesgue outer measure

Comment: It doesnt seem to me but maybe im not thinking about it the right way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need Fubini's theorem. Note that if either is infinite or $0$, then it's trivial, so assume that $m^*(A)$ and $m^*(B)$ are positive and finite. Now, fix $\epsilon>0$. By the definition of outer measure, there exists a countable covering of $A$ by open boxes $(A_j)$ so that $$\sum_j\text{vol} (A_j)<m^*(A)+\frac{\epsilon}{2m^*(B)}.$$ Similarly, we get a countable covering of $B$ by open boxes $(B_k)$ so that
$$\sum_k\text{vol} (B_k)<m^*(B)+\frac{\epsilon}{2\sum\limits_j \text{vol} (A_j)}.$$ Now, observe that 
$$m^*(A)m^*(B)\geq m^*(B)\sum\limits_j\text{vol}(A_j)-\epsilon/2\geq\sum\limits_k\text{vol}(B_k)\sum\limits_{j} \text{vol}(A_j)-\epsilon.$$ Further, $(A_j\times B_k)$ is a countable collection of open boxes covering $A\times B$, with $$\sum\limits_{j,k} \text{vol}(A_j\times B_k)=\sum\limits_j \text{vol}(A_j)\sum\limits_k \text{vol}(B_k),$$ and so by countable subadditivity, $$m^*(A\times B)\leq m^*(A)m^*(B)+\epsilon,$$ where $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary.